# Move items between two listviews in activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I want to implement todo list, takes two listviews in the activity, listview1 and listview2 stacked vertically, listview1 will allow to add items, each item has a label and checkbox, when item's checkbox is clicked, I need to move the item to listview2, the item now in listview2 should show its checkedbox as selected, so listview2 holds the checked items. If item is unchecked in List2, it should go back to list1. How can I achieve this behavior? Code below is what I tried so far.

```
public class ListItem{
  String desc;
  boolean isSelected;
  //..Getters & Setters ...
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>  {
Context context;
List<ListItem> items = null;
List<ListItem> checkedItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
int layoutResourceId;

public ListItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<ListItem> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.items = items;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    protected TextView txtDesc;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
 //   row.setOnClickListener(null); 

    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtDesc = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);

        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                        ListItem currentItem = (ListItem) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                        currentItem.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        if(currentItem.isSelected()){
                          //add item to checkedItems list
                           //remove item from uncheckedlist
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
    }else{
        row = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) row.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(items.get(position));
    }

    ListItem item = items.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    holder.txtDesc.setText(item.getDesc());
    holder.checkbox.setSelected(item.isSelected());

    return row;
}

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

float HINT_FONT_SIZE = 10.0F;
float TEXT_FONT_SIZE = 12.0F;

List<ListItem> uncheckedItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
List<ListItem>checkedItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
//  List<ListItem> items = null;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);



    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ListView listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    final ListItemAdapter adapter = new ListItemAdapter(this,R.layout.details_item_row, uncheckedItems);
   // checkedItems = ListManager.getInstance().getCheckedItems();
    final ListItemAdapter adapter2 = new ListItemAdapter(this,R.layout.details_item_row, checkedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    ........
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case other people looking for an answer to do this, here is my solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="7dp"
>
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/item_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:textStyle="normal"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

```
public class AlphabetListDemo extends Activity {

//String of alphabets //
List<ListItem> alphabets = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
List<ListItem> prods = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

ListView L1, L2;
myAdapter myadp;
myAdapter2 myadp2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet_list_demo);

L1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
L2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);

myadp = new myAdapter(this,alphabets);
myadp2 = new myAdapter2(this,prods);
L1.setAdapter(myadp);
L2.setAdapter(myadp2);

L1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        //add to Other List & update
        prods.add(alphabets.get(arg2));
        L2.setAdapter(myadp2);

        //remove from current List & update
        alphabets.remove(arg2);
        L1.setAdapter(myadp);
    }
});

   L2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        //add to Other List & update
        alphabets.add(prods.get(arg2));
        L1.setAdapter(myadp);

        //remove from current List & update
        prods.remove(arg2);
        L2.setAdapter(myadp2);
    }
});

final EditText textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(textField.getText().length()>0){
            alphabets.add(new ListItem(textField.getText().toString(),false));
            L1.setAdapter(myadp);
        }
    }
});

}


class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>
{
TextView label;
CheckBox checkBox;
View row;
public myAdapter(Context context,List<ListItem>list)
{
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    try{
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        label = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        checkBox= (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        label.setText(alphabets.get(position).description);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prods.add(alphabets.get(position));
                L2.setAdapter(myadp2);

                //remove from current List & update
                alphabets.remove(position);
                L1.setAdapter(myadp);
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return row;
}
}
 // adapter for second list.....
class myAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>
{
TextView label;
CheckBox checkBox;
View row;
public myAdapter2(Context context,List<ListItem>list)
{
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    try{
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        label = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        checkBox= (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        label.setText(prods.get(position).description);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        checkBox.setChecked(true);

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //add to Other List & update
                alphabets.add(prods.get(position));
                L1.setAdapter(myadp);

                //remove from current List & update
                prods.remove(position);
                L2.setAdapter(myadp2);
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return row;
}
}

class ListItem{
public boolean isSelected;
public String description;

ListItem(String description, boolean isSelected){
    this.description = description;
    this.isSelected=isSelected;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, my saviour.

Comment: If both classes are of different model type, how can we achieve this same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I did this:
in listview item: item.setId(youId);
then in onClickListener{onClick(View v){v.getId();}}

Comment: Sorry I am not following, What is item? I have the activity class and the arrayadapter that goes with it, How can I get "listview1" when I am in the adapter?

Comment: i think,Item  its a ListViewRow, you can get him by inflater in getView()